# when using <?php to include a php script am getting error like "<" missing '>' end of tag in a html file

Tags: php, html

i am new to aptana studio, i am getting an error like  "<" missing '>' end of tag in a html file when i am trying add a php script.
Please any one can help me to solving this.

> Here is the screen-shot

[image]

Comment: Could you provide us with a snippet instead of a picture?

Comment: are you trying to insert php in a HTML file? change its extension to .php

Comment: yes,i have changed the extension, its working now..thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a php code in a .html file.

Change your file extension to .php this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file extension to .php as [My name is jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8052447/my-name-is-jeff) suggested or configure your webserver to process .html files too.